# How to generate string elements that don't match a pattern?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

If I have

```
days="1 2 3 4 5 6"

func() {
    echo "lSecure1"
    echo "lSecure"
    echo "lSecure4"
    echo "lSecure6"
    echo "something else"
}
```

and do

```
func | egrep "lSecure[1-6]"
```

then I get

```
lSecure1
lSecure4
lSecure6
```

but what I would like is

```
lSecure2
lSecure3
lSecure5
```

which is all the days that doesn't have a `lSecure` string.

**Question**

My current idea is to use `awk` to split the `$days` and then loop over all combinations.

Is there a better way?

Note that grep -v inverts the sense of a plain grep and does not solve the problem as it does not generate the required strings.

Comment: @fedorqui: READ THE QUESTION. Reversing the sense of grep DOES NOT ANSWER IT.

Comment: Are you trying to generate the strings by tacking on each element of `$day` at the end? Your `func` so far only echos what you have in it.

Comment: @fedorqui, I am shouting because yours is the third suggestion to use -v that I have just commented on (one answer now deleted, one answer still there as at time of writing this comment, then your comment as well) and I feel sorry for the OP when nobody actually reads the question.

Comment: Farceword change policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, but you might consider using `uniq -u` which deletes repeated sequences. For example you can do this with it:

```
( echo "$days" | tr -s ' ' '\n'; func | grep -oP '(?<=lSecure)[1-6]' ) | sort | uniq -u
```

Output:

```
2
3
5
```

Comment: When I try it the first pipe gives `Syntax error: redirection unexpected`

Comment: Which version of `bash` are you using? You can make it more portable by replacing the `tr` bit with: `echo "$days" | tr ' ' '\n'`.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting: see edit, I made the example more portable.

Answer (score 5):

I usually use the `-f` flag of grep for similar purposes. The `<( ... )` code generates a file with all possibilities, grep only selects those not present in the func.

```
func | grep 'lSecure[1-6]' | grep -v -f- <( for i in $days ; do echo lSecure$i ; done )
```

Or, you may prefer it the other way round:

```
for i in $days ; do echo lSecure$i ; done | grep -vf <( func | grep 'lSecure[1-6]' )
```

Answer (score 2):

An `awk` solution:

```
$ func | awk -v i="${days}" 'BEGIN{split(i,a," ")}{gsub(/lSecure/,"");
                             for(var in a)if(a[var] == $0){delete a[var];break}} 
                             END{for(var in a) print "lSecure" a[var]}' | sort
```

We store it in an awk array `a` then while reading a line, get the last number, if it is present in array, then remove that from the array. So at the end, in the array, only those element which have not been found remains. Sort is just to present in a sorted manner :)

Answer (score 2):

```
F=$(func)

for f in $days; do
    if ! echo $F | grep -q lSecure$f; then
    echo lSecure$f
    fi
done
```

Comment: this will call the func again and again. So if the func is having any cumulative side effect, that gets to destroy your main purpose :)

Comment: Nice solution using simple yet elegant method :) +1 for that